# Grouping users by command/shell (the last element of /etc/passwd) with awk

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

using awk I want sth like this:

```
bin/bash: user1, user2
another shell path: user3, user4
```

etc. until all paths and users are displayed

I only figured out how to get all shells from /etc/passwd using 'seen':

```
awk -F: '(!seen[$7]++){print $7}' /etc/passwd
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F: 'NF>5{a[$NF] = ($NF in a ? a[$NF] ", " : "") $1}
END{for (i in a) print i ":", a[i]}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, but I'm not sure how `($NF in a ? a[$NF] ", " : "")` works, could you explain the syntax with the question mark?

Comment: @Flamenco `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3` is like `if (expr1) { expr2 } else { expr3 }` except it evaluates to the result of the appropriate expression.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach using the always-useful [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) utility instead of `awk`:

```
$ datamash -t: -s -g7 collapse 1 < /etc/passwd
/bin/bash:root
/bin/false:syslog,messagebus,landscape,pollinate,colord,systemd-timesync,systemd-network,systemd-resolve,systemd-bus-proxy,uuidd,_apt
/bin/sync:sync
/usr/bin/zsh:shawn
/usr/sbin/nologin:daemon,bin,sys,games,man,lp,mail,news,uucp,proxy,www-data,backup,list,irc,gnats,nobody,sshd
```

(Group by the 7th `:`-delimited field after sorting, and for each group, show all of the first field's values separated by commas)